# C framework like Qt?

Tags: c, qt, frameworks

is there a full-featured framework for C that is similar to [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(toolkit))?

Comment: why similar to Qt. What are you looking for that you can not find in Qt? What kind of application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called [GTK+ (Gimp ToolKit)](http://www.gtk.org/index.php). It's actually quite nice to use, and any program that you write using it will also work on KDE! It's syntax is also pretty nice (for C). It's syntax is very close to Qt's ([see for yourself in this tutorial](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-tutorial/2.17/c39.html#SEC-HELLOWORLD)).

Comment: GTK+ comes with sockets, threads like qt ? Works good on Windows and Mac ? 

Thanks!

Comment: Minor nitpick, Lucas: "it's" means "it is." If you want the possessive, it's "its."

Comment: GNOME is the desktop environment based on GTK+, KDE is based on Qt.

Comment: @rui: Gtk+ builds on top of Glib.  Glib includes GIO whose `GSocket` provides network sockets.  Glib also provides threading support via the `g_thread_*` family of functions.

Comment: @rui: Also see http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html and http://www.gtk-osx.org/ -- Gtk+ is less developed than Qt when it comes to odd platforms like Windows and Mac, but it works.  Actually, it all works marvelously if you go with the X11 backend (on all platforms), but that may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Chris: I just fixed that. You can probably tell English wasn't my best subject. ;-)

Comment: @rui: The best way to say thanks would be to give me the accepted answer, I'm addicted to this rep stuff.

Comment: Doen. Thanks Lucas!
Really appreciate your answers.